# query post by author gender

Tags: wp-query, author, meta-query, user-meta, meta-value

I'm using utimate member plugin on my website.
for each member (author), I have a field to store the member gender. (Homme / Femme).

the data is stored in my database, inside wp_usermeta.

meta key is "gender"
and meta value is either "Homme", or "Femme".

[image]

I'm trying to write a wp-query to display all posts from all the authors, but only "Homme" authors, and another with only "Femme".

here is my wp-query to display all the posts without filtering by gender :

```
<?php $custom_query_args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args ); ?>
```

works fine.

Here is what I've tried so far to get only the posts from "Homme" gender, but it's not working... I think I need to add a reference to post author ID somewhere but I can't find the solution.

```
<?php $custom_query_args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query'             => array(
    array(
              'key' => 'gender',
            'value' => 'Homme',
            'compare' => '='
    ),
  ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args ); ?>
```

I don't know if there's a way of doin it with the plugin itself, but i'm pretty sure it can be done with a simple wp-query.

Can anybody help me with this ?

thanks.

---

here is what I tried, It displays ID of author who are "Homme".

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( array( 
  'meta_key'     => 'gender',
  'meta_value'   => 'Homme',
  'meta_compare' => '='
  ) ); ?>

<?php foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
  echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->ID ) . '</span>';
}

?>
```

works fine.

What I don't know how to do, is to store in my post query the authors ID from this users query, and then use thoses ID in my query like this

array( 'author' => '2,6,17,38' ) )

where '2,6,17,38' should be the ID's of the authors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right you are storing this data in *user* meta. `WP_Query` would have no remote idea how to retrieve that, since it's only aware of *post* meta. The two are completely separate and there is no native way to involve one in queries for another.

Likely you will have to do this in a two step process:

1. Use [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) to retrieve IDs for all authors of one gender and then another.
2. Use [`author__in`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Author_Parameters) argument of `WP_Query` to limit posts to such set of authors.

Working of what you got so far:

```
$blogusers = get_users( array( 
  'meta_key'     => 'gender',
  'meta_value'   => 'Homme',
  'meta_compare' => '=',
   'fields' => 'ID',
  ) );

$custom_query_args = array(

    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'author__in' => $blogusers,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'date',
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $custom_query_args ); ?>
```

Comment: thanks @Rarst, I understand your point, can you please help me with your solution ?

Comment: What specific parts do you have problems with? I would recommend to study documentation I linked to and update question with your progress. :)

Comment: please take a look at my answer below, thanks a lot !

Comment: It's more appropriate to edit original question if you are still working out a solution. You can retrieve just IDs using `'fields' => 'ID'`' in your user query, then just pass it to the respective `WP_Query` argument as per my answer.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply. but I really have troubles to combine the 2 queries. using 'fields' => 'ID', would be nice if you can help me with this !

Comment: thanks, It did not work, but I've changed  'authors__in' => $blogusers by  'author__in' => $blogusers,... there's no "S" at the end of author_in ! thanks a lot for your help, now I understand everything